# How to get image from a custom django registration view

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using using django-registration (redux) and I have created a custom register view for my purposes.

```
class MyRegisterView(RegistrationView):
    form_class = MyCustomForm

    def register(self, form_class):
        new_user = super(MyRegisterView, self).register(form_class)
        cm = CustomModel()
        # cm.profile_picture = form_class.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
        cm.save()
        return new_user
```

In order to get the image I would have to instantiate the form as

```
form_class = MyCustomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

And to do that `request` should be added in `register` method as `def register(self, request, form_class)`

Since `register` method is overridden from `RegistrationView` class the signatures do not match.

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is this sorted or do you stil need help with it?

Comment: Yeah I sorted it. I changed my design. But still I am curious for an answer